# Is this a good example aproach to OOP in JS?

Tags: javascript, oop, class

I have this OOP scheme  based in THREE.JS, and I need to know if I will have problems in the future work with this.

```
var TESTOOP = TESTOOP || { VERSION: '0.1.1' };


//______________________________________________________________________
//OBJECT ROOT CLASS
//______________________________________________________________________
TESTOOP.Object = function(miId){

    //VARS________________________________
    //PRIVATE
    var enable = false;

    //PUBLIC
    this.miId = miId;


    //GETTERS & SETTERS __________________
    this.get_enable = function() {
        return enable;
    };
    this.set_enable = function(val) {
        enable = val;
    };
    this.get_miId = function() {
        return this.miId;
    };
    this.set_miId = function(val) {
        this.miId = val;
    };
};

//METHODS
TESTOOP.Object.prototype = Object.create( TESTOOP.Object.prototype );
TESTOOP.Object.prototype.testNoOverwrite = function (val) {
    console.log("Object.testNoOverwrite (val *4): " + val*4);
};
TESTOOP.Object.prototype.testOverwrite = function () {
    console.log("Object.testOverwrite ID: " + this.miId);
};
TESTOOP.Object.prototype.testOverwriteArgs = function (val) {
    console.log("Object.testOverwriteArgs (val*2): " + val*2);
};






//______________________________________________________________________
//OBJECT CLASS EXTEND & OVERWRITE METHODS
//______________________________________________________________________
TESTOOP.ObjInstance =  function (miId) {
    TESTOOP.Object.call(this, miId);
};
TESTOOP.ObjInstance.prototype = Object.create(TESTOOP.Object.prototype);


//REWRITE METHODS
TESTOOP.ObjInstance.prototype.testOverwrite = function () {
    //SUPER
    TESTOOP.Object.prototype.testOverwrite.call(this);
    console.log("TESTOOP.ObjInstance.testOverwrite ID:" + this.miId);
};
TESTOOP.ObjInstance.prototype.testOverwriteArgs = function (val) {
    //SUPER
    TESTOOP.Object.prototype.testOverwriteArgs.call(this,val);
    console.log("TESTOOP.ObjInstance.testOverwriteArgs (val*3): " + val*3);
};




//______________________________________________________________________
//INTANCE TEST
//______________________________________________________________________
var ObjInstance = new TESTOOP.ObjInstance(0.1);
ObjInstance.set_enable(true);
ObjInstance.testOverwrite();
ObjInstance.set_miId(0.2);
console.log("TESTOOP.ObjInstance, is enable: " + ObjInstance.get_enable());
ObjInstance.testOverwrite();
ObjInstance.testOverwriteArgs(1);
ObjInstance.testNoOverwrite(1);
```

You can play with this in JSbin: http://jsbin.com/apoped/1/edit

Comment: Yes, you'll have problems. All developers have problems with their code. What exactly should we be predicting in order to answer your question?

Comment: I wonder if there is a (much) better option for structuring OOP in JS, or if this solution works well.

Comment: This is a pretty standard pattern in JavaScript. Only difference is that your constructors are located on the `TESTOOP` namespace. There are many discussions about different patterns. I'd suggest searching through those if you want more information. But for all the "clever" approaches people come up with, I personally think the basic pattern you show is best.

Answer (score 2):

From your example uses, it looks like you could use the standard JavaScript object model :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model

It is an interesting read, particuarly if you're in the process of learning to use OOP in JavaScript.

So if you're planning to use OOP in JavaScript, I'd suggest to use the standard model first, using the link above as a guide, as well as [Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/)'s articles on the subject.

If you're a theory guy, you can also read a few classic texts about prototype-based OOP ([Henry Lieberman](http://web.media.mit.edu/~lieber/Lieberary/OOP/Delegation/Delegation.html) comes to mind, and David Ungar's [Organizing Programs Without Classes](http://cs.au.dk/~hosc/local/LaSC-4-3-pp223-242.pdf)).

To sum up, in Douglas Crockford's own words:

> I have been writing JavaScript for 8 years now, and I have never once found need to use an uber function. The super idea is fairly important in the classical pattern, but it appears to be unnecessary in the prototypal and functional patterns. I now see my early attempts to support the classical model in JavaScript as a mistake.

If you really must use class-based OOP, I would recommend reading John Resig's very nice article, [Simple "Class" instanciation](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/) that gives nice subtleties on the subject.

Then you might want to use a proven class-based lib instead of writing your own.

Cheers!